# Tourist guide in Philippines

Tags: guides, philippines

I'm planning to take some members of my family in a trip to the Philippines, and I would like to know what would be the best way to find a Tourist guide? (Preferably someone who can speak Spanish)

I saw few adverts about van rental with driver.. but I don't think he can tour us around, he will take us from A to B and that's it.

Comment: could you perhaps clarify - do you want a tour, and so for how long, or are you after a private guide that would travel with you and your family only?

Comment: I would prefer if it's a private guide but I don't mind if there's like a tour with other people.. and the guide will be for 4-5 days that we'll stay in Manila.. for the rest of the places we'll visit we don't need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I don't like to answer my own question but I found a blog with some information about tourist guide on the Philippines.. with the plus of two of them fluent in Spanish..

http://celdrantours.blogspot.co.uk/2005/07/pause-pause-pause.html

Comment: It's certainly acceptable to answer your own questions - and even to accept those answers! (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)